# $cookies object has no properties

Tags: angularjs, cookies

I'm trying to use the $cookies service using angular  1.4.0-beta.2.

The cookie created by the server gets into `document.cookie`
and also into `$cookies`.
but `$cookies` is just a simple object.
when I check `console.dir($cookies)` there's only keys/values inside.
where's the `get()`, `put()`, `getAll()`functions?

I've tried to check the very basic sample code from https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngCookies/service/$cookies
:

```
    angular.module('cookiesExample', ['ngCookies'])
       .controller('ExampleController', ['$cookies', function($cookies) {
           // Retrieving a cookie
           var favoriteCookie = $cookies.get('myFavorite');
           // Setting a cookie
           $cookies.put('myFavorite', 'oatmeal');
       }]);
```

but it doesn't work. It's probably trivial, but what am I missing?

Comment: Same problem here. Did you find anything?

Comment: Same problem here...

Answer (score 1):

did you remember to update "angular-cookies" too?  it's a plugin, so updating "angular" alone won't work.

I'm using 1.4.0-rc.1, and it works (having updated "angular-cookies" to "1.4.0-rc.1", of course)

Answer (score -1):

I had the same problem. After updating both angular-cookies and angular to the latest version, everything worked as expected. Thanks, tommyTheHitMan, for pointing me in the right direction.